# How to specify an application to work for 7-inch tablets?

Tags: android

I publish an application in play store and this is not support for 7-inch tablets but if it is for 10-inch tablets and cellphones, try to find this application from a 7-inch tablet but does not appear, previously i was published some applications and i had not had any problems like this.

Comment: Do you require any hardware such as a camera? Do ALL 7-inch tablets fail to find the app, or just some?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Post your manifest and also list which tablets you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on your Manifest.xml

```
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="false" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:largestWidthLimitDp="719"
        android:smallScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Because on the Android Developer Guidelines, they write :

> For example, a typical handset screen has a smallestWidth of 320dp, a 7" tablet has a smallestWidth of 600dp, and a 10" tablet has a smallestWidth of 720dp. These values are generally the smallestWidth because they are the shortest dimension of the screen's available space.

[You can find this here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: I found this behaviour quite inconsistent, we had a 7" tablet inflating <600dp layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target for devices of 7" like nexus 7, place the xml file under folder drawable-large-xhdp hope this will help you.